# deploy fastapi (uvicorn) on IIS and Apache

Tags: apache, iis, fastapi

I have several fastapi webservers running today using uvicorn on their own port like `myserver.com:8000`, `myserver.com:8010` and so on. All those processes are started individually by cron today, which is fine, but the users are starting being lost with all this port numbers.
How can I deploy all these servers on IIS and Apache (yes we have Windows servers with IIS too)?
The goal would be to have these applications available as `site1.myserver.com` (pointing to `myserver.com:8000`) and `site2.myserver.com` (pointing to `myserver.com:8010`) etc.

Or just fastapi without uvicorn -> same question?
I'm a bit lost here. :-(

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html for Apache, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing for IIS

Comment: You need to make sure which server used to host application as content server and which server used to proxy request as reverse proxy server if you want to use reverse proxy. However, the host name of your applications seems more like sub domain. If you use sub domain, just bind `site1.myserver.com` to application which is `myserver.com:8000` and same operation to site2. The sub domain all use port 80 and users don't need to add port when enter URL.